# Pinch and double tap zoom for NetworkImageView

Tags: android, android-volley, pinchzoom, touchimageview, networkimageview

I am trying to implement pinch zoom and double tap feature on NetworkImageView inside a ViewPager. I referred to this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Images are loading fine using Volley and NetworkImageView. Even the pinch zoom is working but its not smooth at all. After zooming, the current image is zooming under the next and previous image in ViewPager. Also, the previous image zoom is not resetting.

I tried using Mike Ortiz's new version of TouchImageView code but images are not loading for NetworkImageView.

So,

- Do I need to use new version of TouchImageView for better pinch zoom
  experience and enabling double tap?
- If yes, will it work for NetworkImageView?
- How to fix the issue of zooming under next and
  previous image?
- How to reset the zoom of previous image?

Thanks.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: did you solve this problem ?

Comment: Nopes. But I used imageView along with Volley.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Fixed it by using ImageView along with new version of TouchImageView.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you did this to help others out there who are trying to load network images but also would like the features of TouchImageView.

Comment: hello @johnk1 can you please tell how did you apply zoom on network imageview?

Comment: I think TouchImageView is there in Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/  library

Answer (score 2):

Use this NetworkImageView  instead of the NetworkImageView from volley: https://github.com/geeknizer/Volley-Flickr-Gson-List-GridView-example/blob/master/src/com/androidng/flickr/view/NetworkImageView.java

It is the same but with the corrections to work!

Comment: This works flawlessly if you assign a src in xml for this NetworkImageView.

Answer (score 1):

It is doable!
I have used the codebase from [android imageview zoom](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom). All you need to do is in `ImageViewTouchBase.java` you need to replace class extension by `NetworkImageView`. Works like charm.
You might want to alter the `onDoubleTap` function to have just one level zoom in/out feature.

Comment: how did you set image from url in this.